# Create marker from NID using IP Geolocation Views & Maps that is not affected by exposed filters

Tags: views

I'm using the [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) module to create a map for visitors to see different geotagged locations in a particular city. I am using the Leaflet display as I cannot use Open Layers due to the server using an older version of PHP.

The site is using 1 content type for "locations" and then uses taxonomy to separate the "types" ie - food, drink, car rental, etc.

I need to create an individualized reference point depending on the current node someone is looking at. If someone is looking at car rentals I need a pin for only that car rental location then show all other "types" around it with an exposed filter (food, drinks, etc) giving the user the ability to filter to see only food or only drink.

The view itself is a views page with a wildcard set in the url. I have a second view passing the node ID's for each location.

The issue I'm running into is when someone uses the filter I lose the existing node pin as it isn't part of the filtered content.

I've looked into changing the session variables for the "get my location" block via the current nodes longitude and latitude but ran into a problem with caching.

Is there a way to add a new marker to the existing IP Geolocation Leaflet map (via Jquery or otherwise) that would exist on a different layer and no longer be susceptible to any applied exposed filter?

Answer (score 0):

There is a hook provided in the ip_geoloc.api.php file of the IP Geolocation module that allows you to make modifications (such as adding a point that doesn't exist in your query) to your current view.

The following would load your current nid, query for the particular longitude and latitude fields, then add the marker to the map.

```
function my_custom_module_ip_geoloc_marker_locations_alter(&$marker_locations, &$view) {

  // Need to get current node id to use longitude and latitude
  $param = arg(1);
  $node = node_load($param);
  $field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_geofield');
  $location = $field_items[0];

  // Machine name of your view goes in the line below.
  if ($view->name == 'map') {
    $curpos = new stdClass();
    $curpos->latitude = floatval($location['lat']);
    $curpos->longitude = floatval($location['lon']);
    $curpos->balloon_text = t('Your current location');
    $curpos->marker_color = 'white';

    array_unshift($marker_locations, $curpos);
  }
}
```